# Greek letter as TraditionalForm not working while export to PDF

Tags: export, character-encoding, traditional-form

Below is the code for an example plot,

```
Labeled[ListLinePlot[{Thread[{{0, 360, 720}, {0, 10, 
   20}}]}],{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]\), \(R\)]\)", "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]\),\(R\)]\)"},{Bottom, Left},RotateLabel -> False] // TraditionalForm
Export["/Users/selva/Desktop/Final/Images/test1.jpeg",TraditionalForm[%]]
```

I get the above image.
[image: Correct]

Now if I export it to PDF/EPS using

```
Export["/Users/selva/Desktop/Final/Images/test1.pdf",TraditionalForm[%]]
```

I get below image,
[image: Wrong]

In PDF export, the [CapitalPsi] is no longer in traditional form. Can someone help me with this?

Note: It work in PlotLegends but not in Labeled. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot = ListLinePlot[{Thread[{{0, 360, 720}, {0, 10, 20}}]}, 
        Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
        FrameLabel -> {{FractionBox["\[CapitalPsi]", "R"], ""},
        {FractionBox["\[CapitalPsi]", "R"], ""}}] // DisplayForm

fileNameSave = SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "testplot.pdf", 
                WindowTitle -> "Save plot ..."];
Export[fileNameSave, plot];
```

[image]

Comment: Will this works for EPS as well? Because I am not able to export as EPS

Comment: Exchange "testplot.pdf" with "testplot.eps"...
(don't forget to vote ... "arrow up" or "arrow down")

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Weird it didn't work last time but now it works...

Comment: I tried to but it says I need 15 reputations :(